# Injetar componente dentro de outro componente

Tags: angular, typescript

Eu gostaria de saber, se eu posso injetar um componente dentro de outro componente, eu tenho uma função dentro de um componente e quando eu for fazer alguma coisa em outro componente, gostaria de chamar essa função do outro componente. Eu sei que existe o EventEmitter, porém gostaria de saber se pode acontecer algum erro. Aqui eu consegui fazer a função do outro componente e, é executada perfeitamente, porém desconheço se o uso disso possa trazer algum erro futuro. Utilizei o @Injectable() no componente que eu gostaria de utilizar no outro componente.

Comment: Cara o que vc quer fazer exatamente?? é melhor usar o eventEmmiter, injectable deve ser usado pra serviços e não componentes pq componentes são visuais e serviços não. Talvez seja melhor colocar esse seu metodo num serviço e injetar nos dois componentes.

Comment: posta o código do que vc está tentando fazer.

Comment: Então, funcionou o que queria fazer. Eu também estava pensando em usar o EventEmmiter com um serviço, porém tentei fazer injetando o componente em outro e funcionou. O que eu queria saber é se isso pode trazer alguma problema futuro.

Comment: Cara é péssimo isso e totalmente não o papel de um componente.